# Windows Phone image not visible

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have this problem:
i'm creating my first app in windows phone platform and I put the image files in folder assets/images as usual but when I run the application not recognize images and I don't see the images.

My image format is png.

On iOS and Android I don't have any problem.

Please, can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a code sample and the image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how am able to handle this issue in a alloy project for Android and Windows Phone.

1.Paste PNG files (large.png) in 'assets/android/images' folder and 'assets/windows/images' folder.

2. Access images in code as follows.

```js
    "#large": {

      image: 'images/large.png',

      height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
      width: Ti.UI.FILL

    }


    "#large[platform=android]": {

      image: '../../images/large.png'

    }
```